# Error "Child list for field [Sheet1$] cannot be created" when loading data from excel to datagridview

Tags: vb.net, excel, datagridview, import

I am trying to fill the `DataGridView` (grvExcelData in this case) with data from an excel file. But I am getting the following error:

> "Child list for field [Sheet1$] cannot be created"

Below is my code fragment where I am trying to fill the data grid view. Also I am using Visual Studio 2010 for programming

Thanks for your help in advance

```
Public Sub fillgrid()

    Dim conn1 As String
    conn1 = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & filenamepath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2"""

    Dim connection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(conn1)
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", connection)
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()

    Dim emptyfile As String = "The file does not have any records for inserting."
    Dim selectCmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand()
    selectCmd.Connection = connection

    selectCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"

    If connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        connection.Open()
    End If

    da.SelectCommand = selectCmd
    Dim dsCounter As Integer = da.Fill(ds, "[Sheet1$]")

    If dsCounter = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show(emptyfile, "dsCounter")
    End If

    grvExcelData.DataSource = ds
    grvExcelData.DataMember = "Sheet1"
    grvExcelData.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect

    da.Dispose()

    If connection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        connection.Close()
    connection.Dispose()
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: try replace    grvExcelData.DataSource = ds  grvExcelData.DataMember = "Sheet1" To: grvExcelData.DataSource = ds.Table(0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
grvExcelData.DataMember = "Sheet1"
```

to

```
grvExcelData.DataMember = "[Sheet1$]"
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe a bit late but I am having this same issue and I do have the "[Sheet1$]" as my datamember. any other ideas on this?

Comment: nvm I added the IMEX=1 bit and I got it.